# SQL group by doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have problem with simple sql query. I have table `articles(id, name)` and `posts(id, name, article_id)`.

I need to fetch all posts and sort them by article_id, because article_id from posts is foreign key by id from articles. One post can belong to one article, but one article can has many posts. I tried like this:

```
  SELECT * FROM `posts` GROUP BY article_id
```

Where is my mistake? My error is like this:

> #1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'homestead.posts.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: you need to have some aggregation in the SELECT

Comment: if you want to sort, simply use "ORDER BY" instead of "GROUP BY"

Comment: `group by` is for grouping, not for sorting

Comment: Yes I need to group this ,f.e article 1 has 4 posts, article 2 has 10 posts... But I need this posts too, to show user them

Comment: It is ok for: `One post can belong to one article, but one article can has many posts`, you don't have to group them by yourself .. because when ordering them they will be shown in the result as groups down each other but it will not remove the posts that has shared article.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I need to fetch all posts and sort them by article_id

If you want to sort data, you have to use the `ORDER BY` clause

[MySQl documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sorting-rows.html)

Answer (score 3):

GROUP BY is for aggregation, so use ORDER BY

```
SELECT *
FROM posts
ORDER BY article_id
```